# Reload SQL Query and HTML Drop Down List onblur

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I have a drop down menu that on blur will save the value to my database without refreshing the page at all. This works great, the only problem is that now I need my other drop down menus on the page to also refresh with the updated SQL data.

I know a page refresh would work, but I want to avoid that because my page is long and don't want users to lose their place on it.

So does anyone know how to both refresh the SQL query as well as other drop down menus on the page with an onblur or onchange event?

Thank you!

Comment: Without seeing any code why not just do it in the same event chain as your save operation? Ie when it finishes just call refresh methods on the other components?

Comment: I guess my question is based more out of lack of knowledge. I googled to get the onblur event to pass along the information to another php page which then saves it to the DB. So how could I use what I already have to refresh my query and the drop down menus?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">

function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","updateSQL.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax to fetch data from server and refresh any content  in your page without need to refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks, I did some googling and saw them talking about refreshing div's. My own testing hasn't worked out thus far, can you give me an example of what it would look like to refresh one of the 64 div's that I have with a drop down menu inside of each one? Each div is a separate form and if I could get them all to refresh, pulling the new SQL query at the same time it would answer my question.

Comment: Right now my div's are only in HTML, I assume they need to be converted to jquery so that they can be refreshed properly or can they be refreshed in HTML?